# Current across a diode?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, homework

[image: homework]

So this question seems pretty straightforward to me, just plug the values in and find the answer, however I have no clue as to where im supposed to get Vd from. Can someone explain this or help me understand what I've missed.

Comment: You should know \$v_d\$ based on the circuit surrounding the diode. If you know \$v_d\$ you can solve for \$i_d\$ or if you know \$i_d\$ you can solve for \$v_d\$.

Comment: yea, thats the thing, for some reason Vd isn't given–

Comment: Current is through (and not across); voltage is across. Read your question more carefully - it states it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You are asked to find the operating point such that the *small-signal* resistance is 5 ohms, i.e.

$$\frac{dv_d}{di_d} = 5\,[\Omega]$$

You can obtain this by both sides of the given equation relating voltage and current, then rearranging as needed. The most straightforward way is to rearrange the equation above to a transconductance equation:

$$\begin{align}\frac{di_d}{dv_d} = 0.2\,[\Omega^{-1}] &= \frac{d}{dv_d}\left[I_s \left(e^{\frac{v_d}{v_{th}}}-1\right)\right]\\
0.2\,[\Omega^{-1}] &=  \frac{I_s}{v_{th}} \left(e^{\frac{v_d}{v_{th}}}\right)\\
0.2\,[\text{A}/\text{V}] &= \frac{8\cdot10^{-12}\,[\text{A}]}{0.02\,[\text{V}]} \cdot e^{\frac{v_d}{0.02\,[\text{V}]}}\\
5\cdot10^8 &= e^{\frac{v_d}{0.02\,[\text{V}]}}\\
\ln{5\cdot10^8}&=\frac{v_d}{0.02\,[\text{V}]}\\
{0.02\,[\text{V}]}\cdot\ln{\left(5\cdot10^8\right)} &= v_d 
\end{align}$$

There is now only one unknown on the right side, specifically \$v_d\$ (because \$I_s\$ and \$v_{th}\$ are provided); by substituting back into the original equation you can also find \$i_d\$.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling#Small-signal_modelling) on diode modeling discusses this further, along with a discussion of how one would model AC effects such as the junction capacitance. This sort of small-signal modelling is very useful in analog design, allowing you to analyze more complex devices such as transistors, and complex circuits such as op-amps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111539/discussion-on-answer-by-nanofarad-current-across-a-diode).

Comment: @VoltageSpike Are users [below 20 rep](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) able to use these chat rooms to respond?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is asking you to find \$I_D\$ such that the 'diode' can be thought of as a 5 ohm resistor. In other words, you need to find \$I_D\$ and \$V_D\$ such that \${V_D}/{I_D} = 5\$.  In this case, I would say you just plug and chug various values of \$V_D\$ to find what \$I_D\$ is until you get the right answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right. The question is looking for the value of Id and Vd such that the *small-signal* resistance is 5 ohms.

Comment: @nanofarad The problem says to calculate the numeric value of the DC bias current, \$I_D\$. It never said to find \$V_D\$, so you just use various values for \$V_D\$ to solve for the current. I guess this is meant to show the linear behavior of the diode at small voltage signals.

Comment: You're responding to a different point than the one I'm raising. The issue isn't *which* unknowns we're trying to find, but which operating point we're trying to find them at. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX723.png shows a comparison between large-signal conductance (slope of green line) with small-signal conductance (slope of orange line), both shown applying to the same operating point. Conversely, the operating point for small-signal resistance = 5 ohms is not the same as the operating point for large-signal resistance = 5 ohms (Vd/Id = 5)

Comment: @nanofarad I see what you mean now. I feel sad that I didn't come up with the same answer as you did. Your answer makes much more sense than the way I was going about it.

Comment: No worries, and don't be sad. It's not a clear distinction that stands out right away unless you were specifically taught it. Instead, be happy that you learned and/or clarified a concept, and see if you can apply it to a more complicated circuit such as a circuit containing a transistor.